# Spray: Convert String/ByteString into HttpRequest (or similar)

Tags: scala, spray

I'm using spray and I would like to convert a ByteString that contains the http request into a HttpRequest object (or something similar that will parse the request into an object that represents the request). I'm guessing that there is something in spray-http that does this, but I can't find any examples. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the package [spray.can.parsing](https://github.com/spray/spray/tree/master/spray-can/src/main/scala/spray/can/parsing) is responsible for that, in particular the [HttpRequestPartParser](https://github.com/spray/spray/blob/master/spray-can/src/main/scala/spray/can/parsing/HttpRequestPartParser.scala) class. Unfortunately, it's not public...

Comment: Hopefully public access will be added in the future: https://github.com/spray/spray/issues/685